# Best way to dent a pipe from the inside?

Tags: manufacturing-engineering, metals

I am currently trying to redesign a pipe with 2 dents from the inside.
What is the best way to manufacture something like this, also how would i go about describing this process in a drawing?

In the pictures you can see the pipe before and after the dents are placed. The sides on the pipes are welded on, so it is possible to acces the inside before doing this.

The cutout is present on both pipe, but this is also an extra process that could be done after the denting process.

Material is 3mm AISI 304

EDIT: The design is meant to be used for a prototype, demanding production solutions will not be optimal.

[image: No dents]

[image: Dents]

Answer (score 1):

This is a three part precise jig that can repeat the process many times.

there are left and right solid pipes with a round notch to support the  moving quarter circle hammer shown in black.

When you put the part in the vise you secure the indentation spot with stainless steel belts upside and downside of the spot to be dented, not to let it bulge outside the desired zone, then tighten the vise sliding the round hammer exactly into its spot. then remove the jig and repeat the next piece.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fit it into a mold which has the indents correctly placed and then pressurize the inside - hydraulic pressure with oil or water may be used. A pulse may be effective for this as opposed to a gradual increase in pressure.

Comment: Due to this being a prototype, i was hoping to find a solution with less requirements. for production i agree that this would be a possibility.

Comment: Providing the information that you are working with a prototype would have helped when providing answers.

Comment: I agree, i added the information